# Missing cookies after redirect from a facebook-passport callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js

I have two diferents domains for backend (node and express) and front (vue) and I'm trying to implement login throught facebook using passport-facebook. After getting the user information and JWT, I set the cookies and redirect back to my homepage, but after the redirect, i'm losing the cookies.

My backend is running on localhost:3000 (I'm using **Ngrok** to get a https url for facebook callback) and front on localhost:8080 in a SPA. Here some code:

On my backend:

```
 res.cookie('token', token);
 res.cookie('user', req.user);
 return res.redirect('http://localhost:8080/#/');
```

but after the redirect, none cookie is showed on application's cookie. Someone knows what's going on or a better way to pass an user and JWT throught two differents domains?

Comment: You can't share cookies between two different domains. Other solutions such as passing your token and user in the URI parameter during the redirection, then create cookies on the targeted website.

Comment: Thanks @Sackey. The best solution for this was just pass the user in the URI parameter and then consulting it to gerenate the JWT token. Seems more secure this way.